# Probability of sum of two independent variables given joint density

Tags: probability

Let $x$ and $y$ be $2$ independent random vectors on the unit disk such that their joint density is just $\frac{1}{\pi}$. 
What is the probability that $x+y$ is less than $1$?

Comment: Are you sure they are not independent?

Comment: I suspect you mean that $x$ and $y$ are the *coordinates* of a *point* in the unit disk? However, in that case they're not independent. If you do mean vectors, how do you compare $x+y$ to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean that $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of a point randomly uniformly chosen in the unit disk:

The area of the unit disk below the line $x+y=1$ consists of three quarter-circles with area $\pi/4$ each and a triangle with area $1/2$, so the probability is

$$
\frac{3\pi/4+1/2}\pi=\frac34+\frac1{2\pi}\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly the answer but I am wondering how we can get there through integrating the density function of x and y?

Comment: @Inia: Well, that's essentially the question how to find the areas of a circle and a triangle by integration -- you can find a lot about that by Googling something like "circle area by integration", e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_disk).